A guy finds a flying saucer's hubcap
A guy found a dish like metal object, at the quarry or a construction site. He tried to manipulate it but it was indestructible. He believes it was a hubcap of an spacecraft or flying saucer. He also loves a girl and lives in a condo. And there is also another guy and he is not a good person. In some part of movie this, the guy fell from top floor to ground floor of the other guy's condo apartment. He fell from the empty inner space of the building. I guess this falling guy is the houseowner or something like that. And the bad guy's head collapsed inwards into his body from this upsidedown fall. At the end the flying saucer pulls the hubcap to outer space then takes it.
Approximate year: 90s.
Country of origin: USA.
Actors: I was too young to remember actors but gonna write some actors to give an idea. Main character's actor: he is similar in appearance to Jim Carrey or Brendan Fraiser. Other guy's actor: similar appearance to Tim Curry; he got a beard like him, I guess. But I didn't find anything when I searched their movies.
Genre: I guess it was a comedy.
More details: Main guy finds a metal dish in yellow soil. Soil placed on excavation site and the ground level of site is lower than landscape nearby. So he can dig that dish out from the side of the dune, left from the remaining landscape. I guess there is an airstream trailer nearby. Perhaps he works at here.
He lives in an apartment or condo and he got a small place, perhaps no kitchen, of course cooker nearby at the entrance of the apartment. I guess he got a small window at the main room. He can look the street up from his apartment. He tries to manipulate that metal dish with a blowtorch, hand tools and I guess he tried to burn at the cooker.
His love doesn't know he was loving her until much later.
Movie shows some scenes from the adventures of the main guy then shows his houselife. This type of scenes is shown repeatedly. I guess there is one scene about his fridge. The fridge is in the main room and placed by the wall opposite the entrance door. Window and cooker also placed by that wall.
I guess the main guy sometimes wears a construction worker outfit. And bad guy sometimes appears in a suit. I guess it was dark grey, navy or dark purple. I guess it was a striped suit.

This is Mr. Accident with Yahoo Serious from 2000.

The plot involves a very clumsy but lovable young man named Roger Crumpkin and his UFO-obsessed girlfriend Sunday Valentine (Helen Dallimore), who stumble upon a plan to market eggs laced with nicotine. Crumpkin must risk his job and girlfriend to uncover the plan that just may involve his boss.

Everything single thing you mentioned is there. Only the country & year were slightly off; Well done. The hubcap he found does turn out to be from a UFO in the end, which flies off with it. The trailer:



